# How to sum values under one column that are of the same category in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas data-frame library to sum together a large grouping of data for Covid analysis.
Below is an example of what my table looks like:

```
Category Sub Value1 Value2

A   a1  2  6
    a2  5  7
    a3  4  1
B   b1  6  3
    b2  4  2
C   c1  5  8 
    c2  8  9
    c3  1  1
```

And this is the desired output table:

Note that all of the sub categories of A i.e. (a1,a2,a3) are summed in the output table.

```
Category Value1  Value2
A   11  14
B   10  5
C   14  18
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), edit as text to be copyable or better would be post the code to replicate the dataframe

Comment: `df.groupby('Category')['Value'].sum()`

Comment: By the look of it `df.sum(level=0)` might do

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Virtually any PANDAS tutorial teaches you how to do `groupby` and `sum`

Answer (score 1):

You should try to look up the basics of pandas yourself, before asking questions.

```
df.groupby('Category')[['Value1','Value2']].sum()
```